# Overload Spring Controller method for get with variable request parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create an overloaded controller method in spring for filtering that allows multiple Request Parameters. Some of the answers I have found on here have provide a solution by identifying the request parameters being passed in in the annotation, however, this is insufficient for my needs as I am accepting multiple parameters to filter on and do not want to have to declare all these as request params.

Here is an Example:

```
@RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET )
public List<JSONRepresentation> getJSONRepresentation( 
    @RequestParam Map<String, String> filterParams ) throws ObjectNotFoundException
    {
        // DO STUFF AND FILTER ON VALID PARAMETERS.
    }

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<JSONRepresentation> getJSONRepresentation() throws ObjectNotFoundException
    {
        // DO STUFF AND RETURN ALL.
    }
```

Trying to implement this without having to add a additional value like "/filter" to the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's not possible like that. What you can do it's set `filterParams` as Optional and do your logic to each case:

```
@RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET )
public List<JSONRepresentation> getJSONRepresentation( @RequestParam(required=false) Map<String, String> filterParams ) throws ObjectNotFoundException
{
   if(filterParams != null) {
    // DO STUFF AND FILTER ON VALID PARAMETERS.
   } else {
   // DO STUFF AND RETURN ALL.
   }

}
```

Comment: Ahh, so simple so easy, Thank you very much.

Comment: hmm,, looks like I spoke too soon, filterParams even if not included does not evaluate to null...

Comment: changed to check if( !filterParams.isEmpty() ) problem solved